# What does the & operator mean?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the condition of an if-else statement in c++, here is the snippet where this statement is in (not it's a shorthand version):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        Point newCenter = center;
        newCenter.x += oneEighth.x * (i&4 ? 0.5f : -0.5f);
    }
```

I do understand that the 0.5f holds if the condition is true and -0.5f otherwise, but what does the `i&4` mean?

Comment: It is bitwise "and" operator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation It is unrelated to the `?:` operator here

Comment: What C++ reference docs have you consulted, and what has that told you? [Here's some](http://en.cppreference.com/).

Comment: Actually, the full answer would have been "it depends on context". Used as an unary operator, it's "the address of". As a binary operator, it's indeed a bitwise AND. By the way - both results would be easily found looking at any table of operators in c++ that google finds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here is using two things, firstly it is using the bitwise AND operator `&`, this takes the binary representation of the two integers (`i` and `4`) and computes the bitwise AND of both of these (i.e. for each position in the resulting binary representation of the number we look at the bits at the corresponding position in the two arguments and set the resultant bit to `1` if and only if both bits in the arguments are `1`), secondly, it is using the implicit `int` to `bool` conversion which returns `true` if the integer is not equal to `0`.

For example, if we have `i=7`, then the internal bitwise representation of this in two's complement would be:

```
/*24 0s*/ 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

And the two's complement representation of `4` is `/*24 0s*/ 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0` and so the bitwise AND is `/*24 0s*/ 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0` and as this is not equal to zero it is implictly converted to `true` and so the condition is met.

Alternatively, if we consider `i=2`, then we have the internal representation:

```
/*24 0s*/ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

And thus the bitwise AND gives `/*24 0s*/ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` and thus the condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

The operator is Bitwise AND.
Bitwise binary AND does the logical AND  of the bits in each position of a number in its binary form.

So, in your code, i&4 is true when i is 4, 5, 6, 7, because the base-2 representation of 4 is 100. i&4 will be true when the base-2 representation of i has 1 in the 3-rd position(right-left)

Comment: That list of numbers is not all the possible numbers.

Comment: Yes, but the for statement in the post is for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i), that's why i only listed numbers less than 8